# Can a modern car start after days of interior lights shining?

Tags: battery

I walked outside this morning to find three interior "map" lights shining in my [2009 Toyota Sienna](https://www.kbb.com/toyota/sienna/2009/) minivan. Immediately I assumed our toddler had somehow managed to play with the switches. We hadn't touched the car in roughly 60 hours, so I was more than a little surprised when the van started right up without any labor whatsoever. The doors were unlocked (atypical) so it's possible that someone had attempted a burglary after trying the door and finding it open, but nothing appeared to be missing including a couple electronic devices in plain sight. So we're trying to decide the more likely explanation between a burglar last night and a toddler flipping switches days ago.  What are the chances that three interior lights shining for two and a half days would NOT discharge the battery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the map lights are regular incandescent lights, they consume about 5 watts. A typical car battery has 12 volts * 50 Ah = 600 Wh. This gives 120 hours of operation for the map lights, assuming there's one map light. If there are several, divide that amount by the number of map lights.

However, some newer cars may have LED map lights. They consume about 1 watts each, giving one map light 600 hours of operation. Again, if there are several map lights, divide by the number.

So, the car starting after 60 hours shouldn't be a surprise.

Some diesel engined cars also may have over 50 Ah battery. In this case, the battery lasts for a longer amount of time.

Also, I wouldn't deliberately leave the map lights on for 60 hours, as a dying battery can have a tiny fraction of the capacity of a new battery.

Comment: Touché : well done!

Comment: Thanks. There were three lights on. I considered LEDs but from what I've been able to find these lights were incandescent from the factory and we haven't swapped them. Couldn't look at them to confirm this morning but I'll check this afternoon.

Comment: Note that if the number of lights is large, it may be that the power of one of these lights is lower than 5W. The other answer assumed 1W per light, which may be a better assumption if there's three of them.

Answer (score 1):

So, what is the power of each light multiplied by the hours that they were on (Wh Watt Hours) compared to the energy stored in the battery in Wh? If they are 1W bulbs * 3 * 60 = 180Wh, divide by the voltage 12 gives 15 Amphours which is relatively small if the battery capacity is 100Ah. Also, a long slow load is less of a problem to a battery than a high short one, such as starting where some cars (diesels especially) can demand 1000Amps.